# Nodes and edges overlap each other

Tags: gremlin, gephi, graph-visualization, janusgraph

I'm trying to visualize a graph (using JanusGraph) in Gephi, but all nodes and edges overlap each other in the "Preview" tab.

1. Using Gremlin I'm connecting to the db and create two vertices with one edge:

   ```
   gremlin> graph = JanusGraphFactory.build().set("storage.backend", "cassandra").set("storage.hostname", "127.0.0.1").open(); 
   ==>standardjanusgraph[cassandra:[127.0.0.1]]
   gremlin> v1 = graph.addVertex('human');
   ==>v[122896568]
   gremlin> v2 = graph.addVertex('robot');
   ==>v[40976424]
   gremlin> battle = v1.addEdge('battled', v2, 'time', 22);
   ==>e[215vyv-2163lk-8ufp-oe9m0][122896568-battled->40976424]
   ```
2. Using graph streaming plugin I'm connecting to Gephi and submit the graph:

   ```
   gremlin> :plugin use tinkerpop.gephi
   ==>tinkerpop.gephi activated
   gremlin> :remote connect tinkerpop.gephi
   ==>Connection to Gephi - http://localhost:8080/workspace1 with stepDelay:1000, startRGBColor:[0.0, 1.0, 0.5], colorToFade:g, colorFadeRate:0.7, startSize:10.0,sizeDecrementRate:0.33
   gremlin> :> graph
   ```
3. In Gephi I see correct data in the "Data Laboratory" tab, but here is the result from the "Preview" tab:

   [image]

I'm using:

```
Gephi v 0.9.2
Graph Streaming Plugin v 1.0.3
JanusGraph v 0.2.0
Gremlin v 3.2.6
```

Using Titan the result was correct. What could be done to fix that for JanusGraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> … all nodes and edges overlap each other in the "Preview" tab.

Apply a layout algorithm:

`Overview` > `Layout` > `[layout-algorithm's_name]` > `Run`